How to extend the $p \Rightarrow q$ constraint with logical AND within the $p$ statement for Big-M method?
I am a network engineer who is currently doing some network optimization problem. In my application, there is a requirement for the network delay to be bounded in some interval once some boolean flag is triggered. Particularly, it is of the form $x = 1 \Rightarrow a \le u \le b$. Here $x,u$ are the binary and continuous decision variables repectively. $a,b$ are just some positive number that describe the network delay.
I have been able to reformulate the previous relationship using the big M formulation as follows: $a - M\left( {1 - x} \right) \le u \le b + M\left( {1 - x} \right)$
After sometimes, I reallize that the system can work better if I could enforce the constraint $x = 1\,{\rm{AND}}\,y = 1 \Rightarrow a \le u \le b$. Here $y$ is another boolean decision variable. Sadly, I do not know how to extend the big M method for this constraint due to the logical AND.
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Here are two approaches.  The first one is to impose
$$a - M(2-x-y) \le u \le b + M(2-x-y). \tag1\label1$$
The second is to introduce binary (or just nonnegative) decision variable $z$ and impose
\begin{align}
x+y-1 &\le z \tag2\label2\\
a - M(1-z) \le u &\le b + M(1-z) \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Note that \eqref{1} can be derived by replacing \eqref{2} with an equality and substituting $z=x+y-1$ in \eqref{3}.

So if I dont want to introduce to many variable to my model then $(1)$ is the way to go right ?

Yes, that is correct.
